# How to stop a user from copying plain texts from my page and also from downloading any images in my post, nor can he right click onto the page?

Tags: javascript

[Car-renta-system](https://www.freeprojectz.com/paid-projects/django-python-mysql/car-rental-system),
these people did it awesome, can i know how to do the same please, using django I'm also building a similar project like this

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Any way you should understand that if your text not in image and if someone need to copy he do it.

Comment: control+shift+i on chrome and choose the media tab, filter by images. You can download all images from the site you linked from there. Same for the text content.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it from being copied by removing read permission from the user that shouldn't be able to copy the file. You can use os.chmod for this, or see this page explaining to set permissions with the full Windows security model.